# Data not being sent to view in codeigniter from controller?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to fetch each users login and logout entry from database.
Now a login or logout can be fetched by passing the `emp_id` of user. So whichever user I pass in where condition if will fetch that user's login and logout array.

Now I have multiple users so want to fetch every user's login logout entry. So I used for each loop and looped though user's `emp_id`. and passed it to my model method so I can pass all the `emp_id` and get everyone's login and logout detail.

now this is what i do in controller:

```
 $users = $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();


        foreach ($users as $user) 
        { 
            $emp_id = $user->emp_id; 
            $all_login = $this->data['attendances_logins'] = $this->attendance_m->all_login($emp_id); 
            $all_logout = $this->data['attendances_logouts'] = $this->attendance_m->all_logout($emp_id); 

        }

        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main',$this->data);
```

So if I do `var_dump($users);` I will get all the array of all users.
and if I `var_dump($all_login/all_logout);` I will get each user's login entry and logout entry.

Now in my view if I do 
`var_dump($attendances_logins);` I just get the last user's data. Why does it not print each users's login and logout entry like I get in controller?

This is my code to fetch login and logout entry I have passed `$emp_id` so it returns login and logout for every user:

```
public function all_login($emp_id)
{

    $startDate = new DateTime("first day of last month");
    $endDate = new DateTime("last day of last month");
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('daily_data2');
    $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$emp_id);
    $this->db->where('entry >','100');
    $this->db->where("date(date_data) BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");                                                  
    $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');     
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $res   = $query->result();        
    return $res;

}




public function all_logout($emp_id)
{


      $startDate = new DateTime("first day of last month");
      $endDate = new DateTime("last day of last month");
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('daily_data2');
      $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$emp_id);
      $this->db->where('entry <','100');
      $this->db->where("date(date_data) BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");                                                     
      $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
      $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');
      $query = $this->db->get(); 
      $res   = $query->result();        
      return $res;


}
```

The calculate code::

```
<?php
            $loginarry = $attendances_logins;
            $logoutarry =$attendances_logouts;
            $timeduration=0;
            $login_i=0;
            $logout_i=0;


            echo '<table border="1px"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">';
            echo '<tr><th>Login</th><th>Logout</th><th>Duration</th></tr>';

            //echo ("Array Length = " . count($loginarry)." & ".count($logoutarry)."\n<br/>");
    while(true)
    { 
        if( $login_i >= count($loginarry) && $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
            break;

        if( $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
        {
            //echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n<br/>");
```

echo ("".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." Not AvailableNot Available");

```
//          echo ("<tr> <td>".$loginarry->date_data." </td><td> Data Not Available</td></tr>");
            $login_i++;
            continue;
        }

        if(($login_i+1) == count($loginarry) && ($logout_i+1) < count($logoutarry))
        {
            echo ("<tr><td>Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");
        $logout_i++;
        continue;
        }

        if( $login_i >= count($loginarry))
        {
            echo ("<tr><td> Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<td>Data Not Available</td></td></tr>");
                        $logout_i++;
            continue;
        }
        //echo( "******* ".(new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') . " **** ".(new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U'). "\n<br/>");

        //check if next login time is smaller then current logout time - if so skip current login time
        if($login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
        //if( date_diff(date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data), date_create($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data)) > 0 )
        {
            echo ("<tr><td>".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td><td>Data Not Available</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");
            $login_i++;
            continue;
        }

       //
        if( (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') )
        //if( date_diff(date_create($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data), date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data)) > 0 )
                {
            echo ("<tr><td>Data Not Available </td><td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td><td>Data Not Available</td></tr>");

                        $logout_i++;
                        continue;
                }

        //if more logout entries then skip to last logout entry
        if( $login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && $logout_i < (count($logoutarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') < (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
        {
            echo(" <tr><td> Data Not Available</td> <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n</td> <td>Data Not Available</td> </tr>");
                        $logout_i++;
                        continue;
        }

        echo ("<tr><td> ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data."</td>  <td>".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."</td>");




        $singleduration = ((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U'));
        if($singleduration > 43200)//12 hours X 3600 seconds)
        {   
             //$timeduration += $singleduration;
             echo ("<td class='danger'>Huge duration - not considered - please contact HR (".$singleduration.")</td></tr>");
        }
        else
        {
             $timeduration += $singleduration;
             echo ("<td>".gmdate("H:i:s",$singleduration)."</td></tr>");
        }
        $login_i++;
        $logout_i++;

    }

        echo ("</table>");

        //$finaltime=gmdate("H:i:s",$timeduration);
        //$timedurationstr = ConvertSecondsToStr($timeduration);
        $hours = 0;
        if($timeduration > 3600)
        {
            $hours = floor($timeduration/3600);
            $timeduration -= (3600*$hours);
        }
        $min = 0;
        if($timeduration > 60)
        {
            $min = floor($timeduration/60);
            $timeduration -= (60*$min);
        }
        $seconds = $timeduration;



       //echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total Hours Worked ". $finaltime." Hours</center></h3></div></div>");
       echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total time worked: ". $hours." Hour(s) ".$min." Minute(s) ".$seconds." Second(s)</center></h3></div></div>");
       //echo("<div class= 'row'> <div class ='col-sm-4' style= 'float:right'><h3 class='alert alert-success'><center>Total time worked: ". $timedurationstr." </center></h3></div></div>");

            ?>
```

the Model:

```
 public function all_login($emp_id)
{

    $startDate = new DateTime("first day of last month");
    $endDate = new DateTime("last day of last month");
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('daily_data2');
    $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$emp_id);
    $this->db->where('entry >','100');
    $this->db->where("date(date_data) BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");                                                  
    $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');     
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $res   = $query->result();        
    return $res;

}




public function all_logout($emp_id)
{


      $startDate = new DateTime("first day of last month");
      $endDate = new DateTime("last day of last month");
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('daily_data2');
      $this->db->where('users.emp_id',$emp_id);
      $this->db->where('entry <','100');
      $this->db->where("date(date_data) BETWEEN '" . $startDate->format( 'Y-m-d' ) . "' AND '" . $endDate->format( 'Y-m-d') . "' ");                                                     
      $this->db->order_by("date_data","ASC");
      $this->db->join('users', 'users.emp_id = daily_data2.emp_id','inner');
      $query = $this->db->get(); 
      $res   = $query->result();        
      return $res;


}
```

Comment: You need to store data as an `array`. So in you controller change this line to `$this->data['attendances_logins'][]`.

Comment: Wow that worked @hardiksolanki one more help please

Comment: How to print them along the side of users?

Comment: Do you want to `merge` both data in single `array`?

Comment: @hardiksolanki i have added the view code can u please tell me how to print the login and logout entry besides tha user

Comment: @hardiksolanki Yes i want to do that

Comment: @hardiksolanki once i get login array and logout array i pass i to a code that calculates his total working hours now how to do it for all the users  i am posting the calculation code see

Comment: Do one thing `merge` `attendances_logins` and `attendances_logouts` in your `foreach` loop and make another `array`.

Comment: How to do that @hardiksolanki

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100348/discussion-between-rajan-and-hardik-solanki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this

```
foreach ($users as $user) 
{ 
    $emp_id = $user['emp_id']; 
    $attendances_logins = $this->attendance_m->all_login($emp_id); 
    $attendances_logouts = $this->attendance_m->all_logout($emp_id); 

    $login_logout[] = array(
        'userId' => $emp_id,
        'login' => $attendances_logins, # Count number only 
        'logout' => $attendances_logouts # Count number only 
        );
}

$data['login'] = $login_logout
// load view
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have an error in your PHP code:

```
    $all_login = $this->data['attendances_logins'] = $this->attendance_m->all_login($emp_id); 
    $all_logout = $this->data['attendances_logouts'] = $this->attendance_m->all_logout($emp_id);
```

Should be set like this:

```
$this->data['attendances_logins'] = array();
$this->data['attendances_logouts'] = array();

        foreach ($users as $user) 
        { 
            $this->data['attendances_logins']["$emp_id"] = $this->attendance_m->all_login($emp_id); 
            $this->data['attendances_logouts']["$emp_id"] = $this->attendance_m->all_logout($emp_id); 
        }
```